# Compile Knitr .Rnw from R file, problems with do.call()

Tags: r, knitr, rnw

I'm compiling knitr document from a .R file:

```
knit2pdf(example.Rnw, output=paste0(name,".tex"))
```

But in the document example.Rnw, there's the function:

```
do.call(cbind,mget(as.character(rep_names)))
```

Where rep_names it's the name of some dataframes created by a loop, which i want to merge. The thing is i don't know the extact number of dataframes created.

If i compile the document directly from knitr works perfectly, but when i execute from .R file, he didn't find the objects of rep_names. Example on .pdf output.

```
## Error: value for ’Object_1’ not found
```

Where Object_1 is rep_names[1]. The problem is on which session are the object created?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide any assistance here without a reproducible example. Looking at what you have, I imagine you should change the way you're creating the dataframes to put them in a list rather than as named objects in the global environment. This way you can change the problematic line to `do.call(cbind, listofdfs)`. There are numerous questions and answers here that recommend this strategy.